# Bootstrap collapse does not slideIn

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with bootstrap's `collapse`.
It works as it should, except there is no closing/collapsing animation.

Sliding out works fine and is smooth, but sliding in works just like using hide() on visible element.

Any idea what could be the reason?

```
<tr class="cursor-pointer" data-target="#accordion65" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true">
... 
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="clear-p-b-m" colspan="7">
      <div class="collapse in" id="accordion65" aria-expanded="true" style="">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 task-details"
        ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        ... 
        </div>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: How is collapse triggered? Is there a button?

Comment: data-target is on a <tr> normally you see this on a button or link

Comment: That's what is unusual about it, I don't really want to use button for that, I want to make whole `tr` "clickable".

Answer (score 0):

The only change was to make your code executable, and to change the data-toggle from the TR el to a nested A.

EDITS: I removed the nested A, it was superfluous -- the TR can accept a click in this context. The problem was, the table width was never defined. Not sure what you mean when you say the snippet doesn't work, its working fine for me. I've also changed the collapsed el to start collapsed, and on click to display. Note that, because it's a nested div and not the TR that you're collapsing, you'll still see the second tr even when collapsed.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table>
  <tr class="cursor-pointer" data-target="#accordion65" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true">
    <td>
      click me
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class=" clear-p-b-m" colspan="7">
      <div class="collapse out" id="accordion65" aria-expanded="true" style="">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 task-details">
          zoop
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It would make only certain `td` to react on click, but I want whole `tr` to do that. Problem is that `a` cannot be `tr` descendant , nor `table` descdendant. Is there another way?